# Visualization Ideas

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, nvd3.js

I had mini project from university on visualization. WE pick D3.js for it. They gave data about each country and other details based on it need to create visualization but must not to use Map and Must find 2-3 other visualization ideas to represent this data with filters of countries and it's details

I already decide one way like this [here](http://ameetrana.yzi.me/demos/bubbleChart/)

Just seeking some extra ordinary or unique visualization.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

This is the best list of d3 examples I've seen.  It's got the code for each example too.  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock

There are a few really great libraries to use on top of d3 that can make things real easy and get some extra animations without building it all out yourself.  I really like Dimple.js and NVD3.js.  Here are their websites, both with a bunch of awesome examples.  The guy who wrote and keeps up the Dimple library is on StackOverflow all the time and will answer questions and help you out.

Dimple: http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_index.html

NVD3: http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html